# Having issue making a dropdown prototype function to allow multiple keycodes per value

Tags: jquery, loops, bind

I made a jsfiddle of it, basically what I want is the ability for a user to be able to type in not only the code to get to a dropdown, but an additional value I specify.

In this simple example I want, when a user is focused on the dropdown, for them to be able to type A or 1 to select A, B or 2 to select B, and C or 3 to select C.  With my current implementation only 3 is working, so it seems like the bind is getting overwritten.

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yD7pb/

```
var selectArray = {

    49 : 'A',
    50 : 'B',
    51 : 'C'
};

$.fn.smartSelect = function(array){

    for( var index in array) {

        $(this).bind('keypress',function(event){

            if(event.keyCode == index){

                $(this).val(array[index]);
            }

        });
    }

};

$(document).ready(function() {

$("#testSelect").smartSelect(selectArray);

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to bind the callback function multiple times. Just check to see if it matches one of the keys, and if so set the value:

```
var selectArray = {
    49 : 'A',
    50 : 'B',
    51 : 'C'
};

$.fn.smartSelect = function(array){

    $(this).bind('keypress',function(event){

        if(event.keyCode in selectArray){
            $(this).val(array[event.keyCode]);
        }

    });

};

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#testSelect").smartSelect(selectArray);

});
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yD7pb/5/

Comment: Thank you so much!  One more question: it seems when I go to change the value via a keycode it gets held up if I type the same one twice in a row, do you know why that is?  For example i focus the dropdown then hit A A B, it doesn't move to B after I hit that second A.